# Can we edit Google Android sample project and create app

Tags: licensing, apache-2.0, proprietary-code, open-source-definition

I searched all over the Internet but I was not able to find if anyone has raised this issue. I want to edit some files in an open source sample project provided by Google (change some methods and the package name of all the files), and then deploy the app on the Play Store.

I have the following questions:

1. Can I do this?
2. If I can, do I need to keep any license declaration in my app, or do I need to open source my project?

NOTE: I know that the Google samples are licensed under the Apache License 2.0. But I am not able to find the answers to my questions in the licensing terms.

Comment: Beware that some Android sample apps uses proprietary libraries such as Play Services.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can I do this?

Yes

> 2. If I can, do I need to keep any license declaration in my app, or do I need to open source my project?

You need to keep the original Apache license texts and notices as well as some minimal tracking of the changes you did. See https://enterprise.dejacode.com/license_library/Demo/apache-2.0/#license-text for some details of the requirements

Section 4. of the Apache license is fairly clear on this and quite simple to comply with.

You do not need to make your project open source or Apache-licensed as a whole (though I would strongly encourage this)